# Get closest percentile in a data frame column

Tags: r, dplyr, rank, percentile, closest

I have a large data set where I rank my stock returns using dplyr's percent_rank() function based on the date of the return. My problem is that I want to create breaking points at a percentile level and do not have exactly rounded percentages.

More specifically, I am looking for the number that is closest to every 10th percentile (.1), and here is an extraction of a few values of my data set:

```
sample_data[21:27,]
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  PERMNO Date           Ret Pct_Rank
   <dbl> <date>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1  10065 1969-07-31 -0.142     0.360
2  10065 1969-08-29  0.126     0.331
3  10092 2002-01-31 -0.0569    0.919
4  10092 2002-02-28 -0.134     0.907
5  10092 2002-03-28  0.218     0.893
6  10092 2002-04-30 -0.137     0.701
7  10092 2002-05-31  0.0477    0.461
```

I tried doing a for loop to extract the rows where the distance to the deciles are smallest and then replace them. It seems to work but is extremely inefficient when I want to use it on my original data set, that contains millions of observations.

```
store_vec <- c()
for(i in seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)){
vec <- which.min(abs(sample_data$Pct_Rank - i))
store_vec <- c(store_vec, vec)
}

sample_data$Pct_Rank[store_vec] <- round(sample_data$Pct_Rank[store_vec], digits = 1)
```

- Intended Results:

```
sample_data[21:27,]
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  PERMNO Date           Ret Pct_Rank
   <dbl> <date>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1  10065 1969-07-31 -0.142     0.360
2  10065 1969-08-29  0.126     0.3  
3  10092 2002-01-31 -0.0569    0.919
4  10092 2002-02-28 -0.134     0.9  
5  10092 2002-03-28  0.218     0.893
6  10092 2002-04-30 -0.137     0.7  
7  10092 2002-05-31  0.0477    0.461
```

My biggest issue is that I have a large data set, look over multiple periods of time and need to iterate through each month and stock, so my solution is not feasible large scale.

- Do you have any suggestions on how to avoid using a loop but getting the same results?

P.S. I am not an advanced programmer, so excuse me if I have missed some details

Sample Data for replication:

```
structure(list(PERMNO = c(10057, 10057, 10057, 10057, 10057, 
10057, 10057, 10057, 10057, 10057, 10057, 10065, 10065, 10065, 
10065, 10065, 10065, 10065, 10065, 10065, 10065, 10065, 10092, 
10092, 10092, 10092, 10092, 10092, 10092, 10092, 10092, 10092, 
10092), Date = structure(c(-3107, -3076, -3045, -3016, -2984, 
-2954, -2925, -2892, -2864, -2834, -2803, -427, -398, -366, -335, 
-307, -279, -246, -217, -185, -154, -125, 11718, 11746, 11774, 
11807, 11838, 11866, 11899, 11929, 11960, 11991, 12020), class = "Date"), 
    Ret = c(-0.018018018018018, 0.0229357798165138, -0.031390134529148, 
    -0.0972222222222222, 0.0615384615384615, 0.0386473429951691, 
    -0.0418604651162791, 0.087378640776699, 0.0491071428571429, 
    -0.0297872340425532, -0.0350877192982456, 0.125827814569536, 
    -0.0470588235294118, -0.0123456790123457, -0.04375, -0.0261437908496732, 
    -0.00671140939597315, 0.0135135135135135, -0.0333333333333333, 
    -0.172413793103448, -0.141666666666667, 0.12621359223301, 
    -0.0569146280579132, -0.134462678665961, 0.218348623853211, 
    -0.136546184738956, 0.0476744186046512, 0.148723640399556, 
    -0.0338164251207729, -0.0175000000000001, 0.20763358778626, 
    0.139907290349768, -0.11275415896488), Pct_Rank = c(0.386976744186044, 
    0.641597028783667, 0.713888888888882, 0.581330868761558, 
    0.435185185185187, 0.468952734012974, 0.414814814814816, 
    0.251154201292705, 0.356682027649771, 0.707834101382496, 
    0.602764976958531, 0.042535446205171, 0.0611902766135791, 
    0.0501672240802675, 0.0499999999999999, 0.030176026823135, 
    0.0309106098579783, 0.625104602510468, 0.741854636591494, 
    0.620517097581307, 0.359700249791842, 0.331136738056014, 
    0.919063270336911, 0.906880922950194, 0.892695006190697, 
    0.700745033112567, 0.460613598673312, 0.342963268675197, 
    0.23797780517879, 0.22267871815941, 0.426337448559662, 0.789279869067127, 
    0.935483870967767)), row.names = c(NA, -33L), groups = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(-3107, -3076, -3045, -3016, -2984, -2954, 
    -2925, -2892, -2864, -2834, -2803, -427, -398, -366, -335, 
    -307, -279, -246, -217, -185, -154, -125, 11718, 11746, 11774, 
    11807, 11838, 11866, 11899, 11929, 11960, 11991, 12020), class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
        12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
        23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-33L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: @AaronMontgomery, that seems weird, I dput my data before I edited it. I re-added the structure before editing it, should work now :)

Comment: Oh yes, that's intentional. One pre-loop and one with the results, to show the same sample, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this. Generating deciles using `quantile`, then `within` data create the `"Pct_Rank"` column by those decile values which difference is smallest using `which.min`. In additional columns calculate `abs`olute difference and `rank` them per quantile group using `ave`. Replace only those values which `rank == 1`.

```
qrd <- quantile(sample_data$Pct_Rank, 0:10*.1)

sample_data <- within(sample_data, {
  Pct_dec <- sapply(Pct_Rank, function(x) qrd[which.min(abs(qrd - x))])
  Pct_diff <- abs(Pct_rank - Pct_dec)
  Pct_rank <- ave(Pct_Rank, Pct_dec, FUN=rank)
  Pct_Rank.copy <- Pct_dec 
  Pct_Rank.copy[Pct_rank == 1] <- Pct_dec[Pct_rank == 1] 
  # rm(Pct_dec, Pct_diff, Pct_rank)  ## uncomment/edit this line to remove unwanted columns
})

sample_data[1:10, ]
#    PERMNO       Date         Ret  Pct_Rank Pct_dec Pct_Rank.copy Pct_rank Pct_diff
# 1   10057 1961-06-30 -0.01801802 0.3869767    0.38          0.38        1     0.62
# 2   10057 1961-07-31  0.02293578 0.6415970    0.63          0.63        3     2.37
# 3   10057 1961-08-31 -0.03139013 0.7138889    0.71          0.71        3     2.29
# 4   10057 1961-09-29 -0.09722222 0.5813309    0.59          0.59        1     0.41
# 5   10057 1961-10-31  0.06153846 0.4351852    0.44          0.44        3     2.56
# 6   10057 1961-11-30  0.03864734 0.4689527    0.44          0.44        5     4.56
# 7   10057 1961-12-29 -0.04186047 0.4148148    0.44          0.44        1     0.56
# 8   10057 1962-01-31  0.08737864 0.2511542    0.23          0.23        3     2.77
# 9   10057 1962-02-28  0.04910714 0.3566820    0.34          0.34        3     2.66
# 10  10057 1962-03-30 -0.02978723 0.7078341    0.71          0.71        2     1.29
```

Comment: It's close, but I only want to change a few rows and leave most of them unchanged.

Comment: My goal for this task is to identify the breaking point decile rows. After that I will extract the return and use it as a nominal breaking point value :)

Comment: Can you expand on "change a few rows and leave most of them unchanged"?

Comment: I only want to change the value that is closest to 0.5 to be 0.5 and leave a value like 0.52 = 0.52 (if there is a value closer to 0.5), sorry if it was unclear in the question

Comment: Conceptually, you are right and this is a clever way to do it. I don't know why, but for some reason this particular code is not working. When you run the for loop I posted above, you see that most of the _rounded Pct_Rank_ values have _Pct_rank = 1_, but not all of them. I will see if I can look into this a bit further tomorrow! I appreciate that you put in the effort, thank you for that!

Comment: I moved Pct_diff below Pct_rank in your code, before running it